# How to update value of the element that already exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Something is off in my code since value doesn't get updated. While looping through table elements I'm checking for data attribute. If data attribute 'text-scroll' exist code should append new div element. If doesn't exist I would only update the value for existing element. Here is example of my code:

```
value = $.trim(decodeURIComponent(obj.DATA[elementID]['value']));

if($(this).attr('data-text')){
    console.log('Test Value: '+value);
    if(!$(this).find('div').length){
        $(this).append('<div class="hm_textScroll">'+value+'</div>');
    }else{
        $('.hm_textScroll').val("Test");  
        console.log($(this).find('div').attr('class'))
    }
}
```

As you can see above I set two consoles, one for value and one to update element value. So far first console always output the correct value. Second console does output the element class but value never gets updated. Line above that console should update the value. Can someone tell me where my code is breaking? Is that because my code creates element on fly?

Comment: Did you consider buying an espresso coffee . I'm sure you will solve your own problem after taking a cup ......let me know the updates

Comment: @napi15 Might be something too obvious but I can't find the problem :(

Comment: Indeed , it's very obvious and you need an espresso solid coffee up

Comment: Div always should be in there, I don't append new div that's all.

Comment: div element does not have a value property

Comment: Omg... sorry guys... it is too obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `html()` or `text()` instead of `val()` depending on the type of value you are trying to set to the div. Both works for plain strings but you'll need to use `html()` to insert HTML templates.

```
 $('.hm_textScroll').html("Test");
```

Or

```
$('.hm_textScroll').text("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery class selector returns an object array (more than one element can have the same class), so you should choose the first item from the array.
change this line:
    $('.hm_textScroll').val("Test");
to
    $('.hm_textScroll').[0].val("Test");

Comment: That won't work, $('.hm_textScroll') refers a div, div elements do not have a value property.